# Field Expression to Count Ducts that are Intersecting the Midpoint of a Routeline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, aggregate

I am trying to make my field in a Routeline to automatically count all the ducts that passed throught it. I was able to come up with this code.

```
aggregate(layer:='Duct',
          aggregate:='count',
          expression:='*',
          filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

But I am getting is not quite accurate because it somehow randomly counts ducts. See picture below. (accurate counts are in red)
[image]

What I thought that can solve this issue is to count lines that are intersecting the midpoint of the Routeline. In which I used this code, but now it is just returning 0. Any help?

```
aggregate(layer:='Duct', 
          aggregate:='count', 
          expression:='*', 
          filter:=intersects($geometry, 
                             line_interpolate_point(@current_geometry, 
                                                     length(@current_geometry)/2)))
```

Comment: It is hard to tell from the diagram where the individual footways and ducts start and finish (footways in particular), and also whether footway is a line or a polygon. Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you intend to do. Maybe similar to this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/458593/88814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that both layers are lines, your problem is most likely to do with the fact that you are trying to intersect a point with a line, which will rarely work.

One workaround is to buffer the point by a small amount, which works correctly in my example screenshot below:

```
aggregate(layer:='Duct', 
          aggregate:='count', 
          expression:='*', 
          filter:=intersects($geometry, 
                             buffer(
                                 line_interpolate_point(
                                     geometry(@parent),
                                     length(geometry(@parent))/2),
                                 10)))
```

The image below shows the interpolated points, and the buffered region. The amount of buffering needs to be based on how co-incident the ducts and footways are.

Too large a buffer, and you will get overlap with other ducts. Too small and you will miss the intersections altogether.

[Also worth noting that the @current_geometry variable may not work - see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44499]

[image]

Comment: This expression is working great. The buffer works great on half a meter in which sometimes i do have multiple parallel lines that I digitize. Thank you!